# Package (org.json) not importing after Gradle build -- no errors or feedback

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, org.json, maven-central

I am using [this build file](http://pastebin.com/BZBpntgZ) for my project. I am able to successfully clean and build my project, and am able to import all packages except for [org.json](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.json%7Cjson%7C20141113%7Cjar). I'm running a custom task with --stacktrace, --info, --debug, and --refresh-dependencies which indicates (from what I can tell) that org.json downloads and resolves like all of the others but it's just not in the dependencies folder. I've checked Maven Central and confirmed that the package does exist and that the org and version are correct. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you need this both in sources and tests `compile` dependency will be enough. Remove `testCompile`.

Comment: I've just checked it. It seems that this file is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In Netbeans) Right-clicking the project and selecting 'Reload Project' did the trick.